# Prevent Twitter @ mention when Tweeting through API

Tags: php, html, twitter

I am using the Twitter REST API to post tweets.  However, I do not want tweets that have @ mentions to link to Twitter users, because they are usually referring to users on my site and linking to the wrong Twitter user.  Is there a way to escape the @username string so it will not link to a Twitter user?  I have tried searching online but cannot find a good solution.

I found something about inserting a zero-width space, but the API does not let you insert HTML codes.  Anyone else have a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the Regex you are looking for is something like this: **/(@[a-z0-9]*)/i**.
It will return/find/match all potential Twitternames.

Answer (score 1):

Zero-width space is not an HTML entity, it's just an ordinary Unicode character. Simply write a `U+00A0` (`0xC2 0xA0` if you're writing utf-8 directly) directly into the stream.

You should have `U+00A0` memorized, it's deliberately only one bit different from `U+0020`.

Comment: So if I write this Unicode after the @ sign, it should not be a Twitter username anymore?